# Bootstrap layout: Content not filling browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an administration screen with a sidebar. Everything works well except that the main content does not fill the browser width. I have tried many options but I am unable to solve this puzzle. Your help and advise is appreciated

[image: Screenshot showing gap between content and browser window]

Here is my HTML

```
        <!-- top navigation menu element -->
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                           <li id="departments">
                             <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sitemap"></i> <span>Departments</span>
                           </li>
                           <li id="permissions">
                              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-key"></i> <span>Permissions</span> </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                    </div><!-- .col-sm-3 .col-md-2 .sidebar-offcanvas -->

                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
                        <!--toggle sidebar button-->
                        <p class="visible-xs">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>

                        <h1 class="page-header inline-page-title">Groups</h1>

                        <!-- main content -->

                    </div><!-- .col-sm-9 .col-md-10 .main -->
                </div> <!-- .row .row-offcanvas .row-offcanvas-left -->
            </div><!-- .container-fluid -->
        </div> <!-- #wrap -->
```

And my CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.main {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #dae3e9;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px -2px #f1f1f3;
}

.sidebar-offcanvas {
     min-height: 100%;
}
```

A clearer image showing the gap on the right side - 
[image: see gap on right side]

Comment: Try removing any padding and margin from .main

Comment: Can you post a fiddle on this? Also, as mentioned by @colonelsanders, having padding on .main is going to mess with the default bootstrap col padding. Instead, try wrapping the contents INSIDE the col with .main.

Comment: Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/73aen3qd/4/ you will have to go full screen and stretch the browser window (and result window) to maximum to see the problem

Comment: remove the width of this `.sidebar-offcanvas {
    width: 180px;
}` which is effecting bootstrap class

Comment: Thanks Vitorino - I realized that just now. But please see my question below. Is there anyway to constrain the width of my side menu without losing responsive nature?

Comment: which is the new problem ? `width:180` comes under `min-width : 1200px` i feel it will not effect other devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - it was this piece of CSS that was causing the issue. I removed it and it works well - however leaving me with another problem. How do I constrain the width of my left side navbar without losing the responsive nature? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
    @media only screen 
and (min-width : 1200px) {
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        width: 180px;
    }
}
```